# Cakephp - Multiple users with different profile fields

Tags: php, cakephp

I have three different type of users with different columns for profiles.

I currently have Users table and Groups table with Users table linking to Groups.

How can I set it so that it picks up different type of profiles for each group users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use $belongsTo relation for linking for both table, such that every user belongs to some group.

For that you need to create model of user. Try something like following code

```
class Users extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Users';
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Groups' => array(
            'className' => 'Groups',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id'
        )
    );
}
```